# Cakephp 5: API Access token not matching the hashed token in DB

Tags: php, rest, authentication, cakephp

I'm working a project that requires me to create API endpoint that 3rd party (customers) can integrate into their web site, with this an API access token is required to be able to access the endpoint

So far I have been able to generate the token and hash it and also save the plain token to a database since client/developer should see the plain token however the hashed should be used to check against the hash token field just as we use password and hashedpassword field.

Below is how I'm hashing it to a database:

```
public function beforeSave(EventInterface $event)
{
    $entity = $event->getData('entity');

    if ($entity->isNew()) {
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();

      
        $entity->public_token = Security::hash(Security::randomBytes(32), 'sha256', false);

       
        $entity->token = $hasher->hash($entity->public_token);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Below is included in my aplication.php

```
$authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Token');
          
$authenticationService ->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Token', [
                'queryParam' => 'token',
                'header' => 'Authorization',
                'tokenPrefix' => 'Bearer',
              
            ]);
```

This is included in my AppController.php

```
$this->loadComponent('Authorization.Authorization');

$this->Authentication->setConfig('authenticate', [
    'Token' => [
        'feilds' =>[
            'password' => 'token'
        ],
        'tokenField' => 'token',
        'dataField' => 'token',
        'resolver' => 'Authentication.Orm',
        'hashAlgorithm' => 'sha256',
    ],
]);
```

And my Login method UsersController.php

```
public function login() 
{
    $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
    $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
    if($result->isValid()){
        try {
            $this->Authorization->authorize($this->Authentication->getIdentity()->getOriginalData());
        }catch(\Exception $ex){
            $user = [
                'message' => 'you do not have the credential to access this api'
            ];
            
        } 
      $user = $result->getData(); 
    }else{
        $this->response =$this->response->withStatus(401);
        $user = [
            
            'message' => 'login Details incorrect'
        ];
       pr($result);
       exit;
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
    $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', 'user');
    $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName("Json");

}
```

With the below debugging function added:

```
pr($result);
exit;
```

I get this error:

```
<pre class="pr">Authentication\Authenticator\Result Object
(
    [_status:protected] => FAILURE_CREDENTIALS_MISSING
    [_data:protected] => 
    [_errors:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Login credentials not found
        )

)</pre>
```

A typical API access token is as this

```
'token' => '$2y$10$QW2VLbNkxPIbHNhEMxy2qeNbx2/KI21ff0Hjku0mTYWOK245hOXea'
'public_token' => 'f2f7014286b2079d4e4877cd145ab3d7d3024ebaf8c438be231819448e7ab7b8'
```

My goal is that when I do something like this

```
$http = new Client([
            'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . f2f7014286b2079d4e4877cd145ab3d7d3024ebaf8c438be231819448e7ab7b8]
        ]);
```

it should access the provided URL: http://localhost/myapp/api/v1/orders/listing'

The `Public_token` should authenticate against the field token which has been hashed with it.

However when I use the plain text token(public_token) it returns the error reference above but when I use the HASHED token(token field) it return success.

Please I would be glad if anyone can help me resolve this issue.

Thank you once again in advance.

https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/3/en/authenticators.html#token

https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/3/en/identifiers.html#token

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-api-keys-for-basic-authentication

Comment: Check the fields configuration in your authenticate array. It looks like there's a typo ('feilds' should be 'fields').

Comment: Thanks @Salines, though even with the corrections the error still persists

```
 $this->Authentication->setConfig('authenticate', [
            'Token' => [
                'fields' =>[
                    'password' => 'token'
                ],
                'tokenField' => 'token',
                'dataField' => 'token',
                'resolver' => 'Authentication.Orm',
                'hashAlgorithm' => 'sha256',
            ],
        ]);
```